# JasperReport PDF output in Java Swing

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

In my current project, I am working on some Jasper reports. I have a report which has 2 sub reports in it. I am exporting it to pdf file. If I export a normal jasper report which doesn't have any subreports, the pdf file is working perfectly, when I have subreports, the pdf file is blank. Following is my code:

```
static String reportPath = "D:/Netbeans Projects/Abc/mail_reports/";
public static void getReport() {
    try {
        String reportName = reportPath + "AuctionSale/AuctionSeller/AuctionSeller.jasper";
        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        params.put("sale_date", "2012-01-10");
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName, params, DB.getConn());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:/JasperReport.pdf")); 
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me where did I miss or what do I have to make the report work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could get the print from the following code:

```
String s = Dashboard.mail_seller.getSelectedItem().toString();
            String selected[] = s.split(" -- ");
            String seller_id = selected[0].trim();
            String filename = sale_date + "_" + selected[1].replaceAll(" ", "_").trim() + ".pdf";
            String reportName = reportPath + "AuctionSale/AuctionSellerMail/AuctionSeller.jasper";
            Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            params.put("sale_date", sale_date);
            params.put("seller_id", seller_id);
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportName, params, DB.getConn());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:/Netbeans Projects/JDSons/mail_reports/"+filename+"")); 
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, output); 
            output.flush();
            output.close();
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from [this sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html#subreports) or from the full sample located in *`%jasperreports%\demo\samples\subreport`* folder (from JasperReports distribution package) you can pass the compiled subreport as parameter.

The sample java code:

```java
JasperReport subreport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("build/reports/ProductReport.jasper");

Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ProductsSubreport", subreport);

JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile("build/reports/MasterReport.jasper", parameters, getDemoHsqldbConnection());
```

The snippet from MasterReport jrxml file:

```xml
<parameter name="ProductsSubreport" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"/>
...
<detail>
    ...
        <subreport>
            <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="5" y="25" width="325" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#ffcc99"/>
            <subreportParameter name="City">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="PriceSum" toVariable="ProductTotalPrice" calculation="Sum"/>
            <subreportExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport"><![CDATA[$P{ProductsSubreport}]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
        <subreport>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="335" y="25" width="175" height="20" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" backcolor="#99ccff"/>
            <subreportParameter name="City">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <returnValue subreportVariable="REPORT_COUNT" toVariable="CityAddressCount"/>
            <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA["AddressReport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
</detail>
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I could get the output from the following code. Thanks a lot for your help:

Please see it in my answer